# How do I setup Sitecore Executive Dashboard?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

When I open the Executive Dashboard I get the error "No Traffic Overview data found".  How can I get the traffic overview data wired up to the Executive Dashboard?

For background info, I am running Sitecore 6.5.0 (rev 120706) and I have Sitecore DMS installed and configured.  I am able to access and view reports in Engagement Analytics, I am able to use the Marketing Center to create and track profile keys and personalize content.  Also I am referencing the Engagement Analytics Configuration Reference Guide, and the Executive Dashboard Cookbook to no avail.  Anyone with experience with the Executive Dashboard know if I missed something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Executive dashboard only shows data, if the data on the report has 50 visitors.

You can change this value in

**sitecore/shell/Applications/Reports/Dashboard/Configuration.xml**

Change the value of "MinimumVisitsFilter" to 1, to view all the tracked data for the report

Comment: Thank you for the information.  It is just my dev instance so it's possible I don't have enough traffic for the report.  I think the configuration file you identified is key.