# Sitecore 6.6 Executive Insight Dashboard not get loaded

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

As per in the following screen shot, when I try to open up the executive dashboard in my project it does not get loaded. It's trying to load, but it never gets loaded.

In a fresh Sitecore installation this works.

How can I fix this? What are the configurations do I have to check?

Please help!

[image: Executive Dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

The main Config file is here;
sitecore/shell/Applications/Reports/Dashboard/Configuration.xml

Also we had an issue where the dropdownlist at the top of our dashboard was not listing our websites. We have a multisite environment using Multiple Site Manager shared source module to maintain multiple site configurations. It turned out that the Executive Inside Dashboard does not recognize this modules site definitions, it only lists sites defined in Web.Config or AppConfig include files. We have since stopped using the module and defined our sites in Web.Config.

Finally check the minimumvisitsfilter as per this;
[How do I setup Sitecore Executive Dashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15751166/how-do-i-setup-sitecore-executive-dashboard)

Answer (score 0):

please try to do next steps:

Please try to:

1) force the data in the cache tables to be updated: use the "Refresh Aggregated Data in Reports" option in the Control Panel > Analytics.

2) clear the cache:
Executive Dashboard works with the client and server cache to avoid frequent requests to the Analytics database. Sometimes the cache could be the cause of not updated reports, so make sure that it is configured correctly.

The server cache is stored in the data folder, in the ‘Dashboard reports’ directory. To clear the cache, just remove this folder and the next Dashboard run will send a new request to Analytics database for creating a new cache (the client cache must be cleared as well).
Check the following article for more information:

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Scrapbook/Executive%20Dashboard%20Tips.aspx
Note: Please do not open Executive Dashboard between above steps.

Answer (score 0):

There may possibly some sitecore file is corrupted or missing, check sitecore folder. You can compare it with fresh sitecore