# Executive Insight Dashboard does not update after opening first time

Tags: seo, sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-dms

I am trying to generate some initial reports for Sitecore DMS but don't why the report is not getting updated even after 8 hours.

What should be changed in Sitecore Configurations to regenerate or process the latest DMS reports?

I have tried to change the settings guided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15762457/468718).

[image: Executive Insight Dashboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data for the dashboard is only updated every 24 hours.  See section 4.1 in the [executive dashboard cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/66/executive_dashboard_cookbook_sc66-a4.pdf) for reference.

You may also manually hit the "refresh" button that is in the lower-left of your screenshot, above the "View by" dropdown if you need immediate results.